# Uncaught TypeError: function call() { [native code] } is not a function reactjs

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, yarnpkg

I have created reactjs build with `yarn build` and it successfully created. when I deployed code on server it giving error see: http://prntscr.com/npbia7
Build see: http://prntscr.com/npb62e

Please suggest how it will be fixed

[image]

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I worked in Angular 6 and Firebase, and I faced similar error for a while.

To fix it, follow these steps carefully:

1. `ng build`
2. `npm install firebase-tools -g` (install it even if you've already installed)
3. `firebase init hosting`
4. `firebase deploy --only hosting`